Cross ratio of lines in the projective space
I recently started learning about projective geometry.
I learned that the cross ratio of 4 points {$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$} in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is defined to be:
$C(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{21} \\
x_{12} & x_{22}
\end{vmatrix}
\div \begin{vmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{31} \\
x_{12} & x_{32} \end{vmatrix}}
{\begin{vmatrix}
x_{21} & x_{41} \\
x_{22} & x_{42}
\end{vmatrix}
\div \begin{vmatrix}
x_{31} & x_{41} \\
x_{32} & x_{42} \end{vmatrix}}$
I am now wondering about the cross ratio in $\mathbb{P}^2$, that is, given a point p in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^2$ and four lines:  {$\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3,\ell_4$} in the pencil of lines centered at p, how does one computes the cross-ratio of the lines?
MY thought so far:
I thought about finding the base of the pencil, and then expressing the lines with that base. from that point, I thought about transferring these lines to point in   $\mathbb{P}^1$ in order to use the cross ratio defiend above.
